# Create Poisson-like distribution with N random numbers whose sum is a constant (C)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random, numbers

I want to generate a random Poisson number distribution where the sum of the generated numbers is 1000 and the lower-upper bound of the distribution is (3-30).

**I can use numpy to generate random number:**

```
 
In [2]: np.random.poisson(5, 150)
array([ 4,  4,  6,  4,  8,  6,  4,  2,  6,  8,  8,  8,  1,  4,  3,  4,  1,
        3,  7,  6,  7,  4,  5,  5,  7,  6,  5,  3,  3,  5,  4,  6,  2,  0,
        3,  5,  6,  2,  5,  2,  4,  7,  4,  7,  8,  5,  6,  1,  4,  4,  7,
        4,  7,  2,  7,  4,  3,  8, 10,  2,  5,  7,  6,  3,  5,  7,  8,  5,
        4,  7,  8,  8,  2,  2, 10,  6,  3,  5,  2,  5,  5,  6,  4,  6,  4,
        0,  4,  3,  5,  8,  6,  7,  4,  4,  4,  3,  3,  4,  4,  6,  7,  6,
        3,  9,  7,  7,  4,  5,  2,  4,  3,  6,  5,  6,  3,  6,  8,  9,  6,
        3,  4,  4,  7,  3,  9, 12,  4,  5,  5,  7,  6,  5,  2, 10,  1,  3,
        4,  4,  6,  5,  4,  4,  7,  5,  6,  5,  7,  2,  5,  5])
```

**But, I want to add something more to it :**

```
- The random number should be minimal of 3 and max of 30 
- The sum of the generated random number should be 1000.
```

I know, I may not be creating an exact Poisson distribution if I manipulate. But, I want something like Poisson but with suggested controls.

Comment: Is the number of values always fixed?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. If it has a minimum of 3 it's not Poisson. If the random variables add to a constant they're not independent Poisson.

Comment: How many numbers in one sample?

Comment: @Denziloe making minimum of 3 with Poisson is easy - just return poisson(lambda)+3. Making upper limit of 30 is hard...

Comment: @Denziloe You can shift any distribution with an additive constant.  And constraints like adding to a particular sum are found all the time in probability, it just means you have fewer degrees of freedom than observations.

Comment: The question asks for a Poisson random number distribution. 3 + Poisson is not Poisson.

Comment: @Denziloe The question asks for "something like possion"(sic).  A shifted Poisson is a reasonable interpretation.

Comment: @pjs and Severin: It doesn't matter how many numbers but the sum of the distribution should sum to 1000. I understand that 3+ isn't possible but it will be something like possion. I was thinking about generating random possion distribution and add 3 to each element of any array, but getting the sum to 1000 is becoming a problem.

Comment: Without trying to be difficult, I honestly don't see what it means to say 3 + Poisson is particularly "like Poisson" any more than any other distribution. Many of the values in the Poisson in the question are below 3, so shifting them along will make something that does not look like any Poisson.

Comment: @Denziloe: I may know better about whether if adding +3 will deviate the data from being possion. But, I am willing to make this problem work first. The issue of 3+ is n't big, but the issue of getting sum to 1000 is. I was thinking if creating an array of say 200 possion distribution and then selecting them in a loop until a sum of 1000 is reached is a good option.

Comment: @Denziloe People take "pure" distributions and rescale/translate them all the time for modeling purposes.  If two distributions have identical histograms other than the labels on the axes, I think it's fair to say they're similar.

Comment: @Denziloe: Sorry the earlier comment should have said, "I may not know better...". You know typos happen and I can no more edit that comment.

Comment: @pjs: True. That is what I exactly want. But, I can having issues with getting the sum at 1000. I am doing a modeling and I think the purpose of the modeling is just to recreate the similar or alike condition.

Comment: @pjs, I wrote an answer and would be grateful for comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's yet another alternative, based on pre-allocating the minimum per bin, calculating how many observations remain, and dialing in a Poisson rate for each remaining bin determined by how many observations and how many bins remain, but subject to acceptance/rejection based on the upper bound per bin.

Since a Poisson is a count of how many observations fell in an interval, if not all have been allocated by the initial stage they are randomly allocated one-by-one to bins with remaining capacity.

Here it is:

```
import numpy as np

def make_poissonish(n, num_bins):
    if n > 30 * num_bins:
        print("requested n exceeds 30 / bin")
        exit(-1)
    if n < 3 * num_bins:
        print("requested n cannot fill 3 / bin")
        exit(-1)

    # Disperse minimum quantity per bin in all bins, then determine remainder
    lst = [3 for _ in range(num_bins)]
    number_remaining = n - num_bins * 3

    # Allocate counts to all bins using a truncated Poisson
    for i in range(num_bins):
        # dial the rate up or down depending on whether we're falling
        # behind or getting ahead in allocating observations to bins
        rate = number_remaining / float(num_bins - i)  # avg per remaining bin

        # keep generating until we meet the constraint requirement (acceptance/rejection)
        while True:
            x = np.random.poisson(rate)
            if x <= 27 and x <= number_remaining: break
        # Found an acceptable count, put it in this bin and move on
        lst[i] += x
        number_remaining -= x

    # If there are still observations remaining, disperse them
    # randomly across bins that have remaining capacity
    while number_remaining > 0:
        i = np.random.randint(0, num_bins)
        if lst[i] >= 30:    # not this one, it's already full!
            continue
        lst[i] += 1
        number_remaining -= 1
    return lst
```

Sample output:

```
result = make_poissonish(150, 10)
print(result)                    # => [16, 19, 11, 16, 21, 18, 12, 17, 8, 12]
print(sum(result))               # => 150

result = make_poissonish(50, 10)
print(result)                    # => [3, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 15, 3, 6, 3]
print(sum(result))               # => 50
```

Comment: this really was helpful. I made some modifications to fit it to my needs. Would it be possible to reach to you (via email) for some discussions on statistics and modeling.

Answer (score 2):

Let me write something which could work or not, we'll see

Property of Poisson distribution is that one parameter - λ - is measure of mean and variance at the same time. Lets try another distribution, which really sums to 1000 and close enough to Poisson.

I would try [Multinomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution). Let's consider we're sampling 200 numbers from multinomial. We will shift each sampled number by 3, so minimum boundary condition is satisfied. It means that for sampled multinomial sum (`n` parameter) is equal to 1000 - 3*200 = 400. Probabilities p<sub>i</sub> will be set to 1/200.

Thus, for multinomial mean E[x<sub>i</sub>] = n p<sub>i</sub> = 400/200 = 2. Variance from multinomial would be = n p<sub>i</sub> (1 - p<sub>i</sub>), and because p<sub>i</sub> is very small, term (1 - p<sub>i</sub>) would be pretty much close to 1, thus making sampled integers resembling Poisson with mean equal to variance. Problem is, after shift mean would be 5, but variance stays at ~2.

Anyway, some code.

```
import numpy as np

N = 200
shift = 3
n = 1000 - N*shift
p = [1.0 / float(N)] * N

q = np.random.multinomial(n, p, size=1)
print(np.sum(q))
print(np.mean(q))
print(np.var(q))

result = q + shift
print(np.sum(result))
print(np.mean(result))
print(np.var(result))
```

Comment: `p = [1.0 / float(N)] * N` ? I think you meant `*n`. This looks like a good way of approaching this issue. I am going to simutale using this and make any required improvements.

Comment: @everestial007 No, I meant `N`, number of items to be sampled. So array `p_i` contains probabilities and is normalized. Please share results of your simulation, I'm quite curious if it works, and if it won't - why it didn't

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do it using while loop and random module and it will do the job :

```
from random import randint
nums_sum = 0
nums_lst = list()
while nums_sum < 1000:
    n = randint(3, 31)
    nums_sum += n
    nums_lst.append(str(n))
    print(nums_sum)
    if 1000-nums_sum > 30: # means if the sum is more than 30 then complete ..
        continue
    else:
        nums_sum += 1000-nums_sum
print(nums_sum)
print(nums_lst)
```

so simple .

Comment: Hi hassan this is a good way of getting over the issue, but my concern is that the distribution should be possion in nature. So, the average probability of getting mean is higher than number at the end of the distribution. With randit probability of getting any number is basically the same.